# Looking for WCF docs on creating custom Transport Channels

Tags: .net, wcf, documentation

Well, it appears that now that WCF has been out for a while, the WCF Channels Mini Book that is referenced in this great article (http://winterdom.com/weblog/2007/02/14/WritingAWCFTransportChannelPart1.aspx) provided by SO user tomasr (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10292/tomasr) is no longer available since Microsoft retired the netfx3.com domain.

Does anybody have a copy of the ebook around, assuming that it was published as a PDF or as a Word document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the equivalent in the MSDN docs for the .NET 3.5.  It's in the Extending the Channel Layer section of the Exentending WCF section of the Windows Communication Foundation section: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731088.aspx